# A mnemonic for the order of CSS margin and padding shorthand properties

Tags: css, mnemonics

I can never remember the order of the shorthand property for setting the margin or padding in one declaration. That is:

```
margin-top:    2px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
margin-left:   3px;
margin-right:  8px;
```

may be written as

```
margin: 2px 8px 4px 3px;
```

Yes I understand that one can visualise the order by thinking of a clock, starting at midday and moving clockwise. But I keep forgetting about that. I need to recall the order top, right, bottom, left textually.

Hence, `T R B L`.

Something like This [R-noun] [B-verb] [L-nouns] is perhaps the way to go but I feel myself lacking inspiration. If anyone has come across a useful mnemonic for this I'd love to hear it. Like a good meme, I'm sure once I get something lodged in my brain I will be unlikely to forget it.

Comment: This is overkill for anyone familiar with analogue clocks. Abstractions like words and acronyms are unnatural to the human mind, remembering T R B L and then manually converting each letter to a physical orientation is making life more complicated than it needs to be IMO. Much better to remember the order visually, you're working in a visual medium in this context after all :D.

Comment: Should also remember what happens if only two or three values are given.  For example "margin: 3em 5em;" and "margin: 3em 5em 6em;".  In the first one, 3em is used for the top and bottom, and 5 for left and right sides.  In the second one, 3 for top, 5 for left and right, and 6 for the bottom.  I assume it's easy to remember what happens if only one value is given.

Comment: I love the answers, but this has got to be the most ridiculous question only because of the way you approach it. You completely lost me with the nouns and verbs. It's a box, put a clock in it and be done with it.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

If you don't get it right, there will be TRouBLe

Comment: No TRouBLe to remember if you remove vowels

Comment: @zzapper: OUch --- EEEks. I got it wrong and removed the consonants.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/remember-the-order-of-marginpadding-shorthand-with-trouble/

Answer (score 78):

Actually the clock thing works perfectly.
It is the most intuitive way to remember it, at least for me.

Comment: And it works pictorially too... most of the time, you're going to thinking along visual lines anyhow.

Answer (score 25):

Tricky Rectangle Border Logic ?

Comment: I haven't heard that one before, but I like it :)

Answer (score 21):

Why don't just remember that the order goes clockwise starting from the TOP:

**TOP -> RIGHT -> BOTTOM -> LEFT**

Answer (score 16):

Another attempt:

Tyrannosaurus Rex : Big Lizard

Answer (score 13):

The Really Big Lebowski

Answer (score 12):

Just think clockwise, it's the easiest way. Starts at the top and goes around... much easier to remember than some silly phrase (provided you know how to read a clock...)

Answer (score 9):

**T** **R** o u **B** **L** e.

Answer (score 8):

Timewise Rotation, Bit Lame?

Answer (score 6):

Try Roast Beef Leftovers ?

Answer (score 4):

"**T**op,Right,Bottom,Left"
**R**eally
**B**ad
**L**imerick

Answer (score 4):

The clock trick works for the 4 number shortcut, but is there any logic to the 3 and 2 number shortcuts? 1 number and it applies to everything, and that makes sense, but

```
1 = (T/R/b/l) 
2 = (T=b) (R=l)   
3 = (T) (R=l) (b)  
4 = (T) (R) (b) (l)
```

It just doesn't seem logical at all. But... 
First value pertains to Top,
Second pertains to the Right,
Third is the bottom and 
Fourth is the left;
A number is not specified if it's the same as its opposite. Horizontal and vertical MUST be declared unless all values are identical.

In other words, you always specify the Top and Right values, bottom and left fall in as required.

Answer (score 2):

Think that you're reading Arabii or Hebrew: read from the top of the page, right to left to the bottom. ;P The good thing about this "rule" is that it works for the 3 value version too:
`top right-and-left bottom`

Actually, i allso thought it was hard to remember, but as soon as I discovered it was the direction of the clock it was easier.

Answer (score 2):

TRouBLe is best for me. And if only 3 values are shown, it's Top, Sides, Bottom - which for UK users spells TSB (the bank the government had to bail out using our money) - so TRouBLe and TSB are closely linked!

Answer (score 2):

TROUBLE is always a secondary reminder for me, since I first think of the clockwise direction but might need to remember where you start; however, the 3-value shorthand was always confusing me until I realized the middle, (or second) value needs to represent two values (the sides). So, three values - the 2nd being 2 values - helps me remember that.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It is</strike>

```
top
right 
bottom 
left
```

not what you have

**T**hink
**R**ight 
**B**efore you
**L**eap

Comment: There is an extra "you".

Answer (score 1):

Theres always the town of TRumBuLl Connecticut

Answer (score 1):

**T**op **R**amen, **B**ottom, **L**unch

Answer (score 1):

Remember driving lesson:

Turn Right Before Left

Answer (score 0):

If you're old enough to remember the original Star Trek TV series (you know, with Capt Kirk), well first of all, you're too damn old. But there is "**The Trouble with Tribbles**" episode. Both nouns in the title work. I've used that in the past, but also prefer the clock analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you strike with a given situation, just think of a clock-wise rotation i.e., way the clock rotates from 0 to 60 in a circular rotation.

Clock thing is easier to remember than the word TRouBLe (as marked answer) in my opinion since the word `trouble` belongs to English language and all those minds native to English language might find it easier to remember the word TRouBLe in relevancy to the given situation but not others who only use English language when they really have to.

Same is not true with clock-wise rotation of a clock, when it comes to remembering something (as asked it the question) since clock-wise-rotation is a very well-known phenomena world-wise.

Answer (score 0):

A few abbreviations (one may consider the one which sounds familiar):

1. **TR**OU**BL**E (***TR***OU**BL**ESHOOT,***TR***OU**BL**ESOME)
2. **T**E**R**RI**BL**E
3. **TR**IB**BL**E
4. **T**he **R**oyal **B**ritish **L**egion
5. **T**obacco **R**oad **B**asketball **L**eague
6. **T**emporary **R**evenue **B**orrowing **L**imit
7. **T**ransformational **R**ule-**B**ased **L**earning

Answer (score 0):

**T** he

**R** omans

**B** rought

**L** atin

(among some other things...).